# array of non-repeating random numbers in visual basic not working

Tags: arrays, vba, random

I have the following code that receives a number and returns a random number between two ranges depending on the number passed by parameter.

```
Private Function GeneraNumero(ByVal columna)
        Dim value As Integer
        If columna = 0 Then
            value = CInt((1 - 9) * Rnd() + 9)

        ElseIf columna = 1 Then
            value = CInt((10 - 19) * Rnd() + 19)
        ElseIf columna = 2 Then
            value = CInt((20 - 29) * Rnd() + 29)
        ElseIf columna = 3 Then
            value = CInt((30 - 39) * Rnd() + 39)
        ElseIf columna = 4 Then
            value = CInt((40 - 49) * Rnd() + 49)
        ElseIf columna = 5 Then
            value = CInt((50 - 59) * Rnd() + 59)
        ElseIf columna = 6 Then
            value = CInt((60 - 69) * Rnd() + 69)
        ElseIf columna = 7 Then
            value = CInt((70 - 79) * Rnd() + 79)
        ElseIf columna = 8 Then
            value = CInt((80 - 90) * Rnd() + 90)
        End If
        Return value


    End Function
```

and this part is in charge of calling the previous code passing a different number as a parameter, after obtaining the random number I go through an array of numbers created to store them and if it is not found there then I save it if it is found I repeat the loop, then I create a button to which I assign that number as text and put the button in a TableLayoutPanel.

So far so good, the only thing that happens is that there is always some repeated number and I am not able to see the failure.

```
Private Sub GenerarCarton()
        Dim repetido As Boolean = False
        filas = 3
        columnas = 9
        Dim numeros(27) As Integer
        Dim aleatorio As Integer
        Dim numero As Integer
        For i = 0 To filas - 1
            For j = 0 To columnas - 1
                Do
                    aleatorio = GeneraNumero(j)
                    For k = 0 To numeros.Length - 1
                        If numeros(k) <> aleatorio Then
                            numeros(k) = aleatorio
                            numero = aleatorio
                            repetido = True
                        Else
                            repetido = False
                        End If
                    Next
                Loop While repetido = True

                Dim miboton As New Button

                With miboton
                    .Name = "boton" & i & j
                    .Width = 50
                    .Height = 50
                    .Text = numero
                    .Top = .Height * ((i - 1) Mod filas) + 100
                    .Left = .Width * (j) + 10
                End With
                TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(miboton)
                AddHandler miboton.MouseDown, AddressOf miclick
            Next j

        Next i

    End Sub
```

[image: output image description]

Comment: A common method for avoiding repeating numbers is to put all the possible numbers in an array and shuffle the array.  Take as many numbers as needed from the front of the array.  Some languages have a built-in shuffle function, otherwise use the Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

There is no failure. Even if these are pseudo random numbers, a basic principle is, that every number is independent - it doesn't "know" about any previous number, it is random "on its own".

Thus, with so few possible numbers that you have, it would rather be unlikely, that dupes would never be present.

If you wish unique numbers, create a list of these for each range, then sort these randomly (by the native return value of *Rnd*, which is a *Single* having many decimals), and pick the top 3.

If you wish truly random numbers, study my project [VBA.Random](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Random).